# In Rails, if an enum has a space, is there a way to access its query shortcut methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums, model

I have a model with an enum attribute called "status." One of the values ("in progress") has a space.

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: [:scheduled, :"in progress", :final]
end
```

I can use the query methods for the other values.

```
my_game.scheduled?
true

my_game.final?
false

my_game.final! => true
```

I can set the status to *in progress* by updating the attribute:

```
my_game.status = "in progress"
```

And I can get the status by checking the attribute:

```
my_game.status
"in progress"

my_game.status=="in progress"
true
```

**But, is there a way to access the query method?**

```
my_game."in progress"?
```

Comment: I would argue that you shoud change your enum to `enum status: [:scheduled, :in_progress, :final]` just to avoid all the WAAT!?! moments it may cause.  Use the I18n module to map the enum states to user friendly texts.

Comment: For example if I had to work on your app and had to spend 20 minutes  finding out that I had to use `game.statuses[:"in progress"]` instead of the expected  `game.statuses[:in_progress]` to get the enum mapping I wouldn't be very happy.

Comment: Very smart @max - answer updated - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it turns out Rails makes the query methods available by adding an underscore:

```
my_game.in_progress! => true

my_game.in_progress?
true
```

However, you can avoid the headache by using underscores in the enum value to begin with:

```
enum status: [:scheduled, :in_progress, :final]
```

And then reference the query methods as you normally would:

```
my_game.in_progress?
false

my_game.in_progress! => true

my_game.in_progress?
true
```

After that, use the [i18n module](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) to give the enum value user friendly text.